JPA: Duplicate Entry When Adding Child Entity (One-To-Many)
I am using Java 21, Spring Boot 3+ and Spring Data JPA.
While making some changes, I am facing a problem with spring data jpa, mapping between entities
causing undesired effects when being translated to SQL statements.
I have the following database schema:
CREATE TABLE `user`
(
    `id`   varchar(255),
    `username` varchar(40),
    `first_name` varchar(40),
    `last_name` varchar(40),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `authority`
(
    `authority` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `user_id`   varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`authority`, `user_id`),
    KEY    `FK6edqftupukawiexbmveftr` (`user_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK6edqftupukiexbmveftdyrr` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
);

Below is the mapping in java:
@Entity
@IdClass(AuthorityKey.class)
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Authority {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
    @Id
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AuthorityType authority;


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Authority)) return false;

        Authority authorityObj = (Authority) o;

        if (!Objects.equals(user, authorityObj.user)) return false;
        return Objects.equals(authority, authorityObj.authority);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(user, authority);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Authority{" +
                "user='" + user + '\'' +
                ", authority='" + authority + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String username;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof User)) return false;
        return id != null && id.equals(((User) o).getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(id);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", username='" + username + '\'' +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
public class AuthorityKey implements Serializable {
    private User user;
    private AuthorityType authority;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof AuthorityKey)) return false;

        AuthorityKey authorityKey = (AuthorityKey) o;

        if (Objects.equals(user,authorityKey.user)) return false;
        return authority == authorityKey.authority;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(user, authority);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AuthorityKey{" +
                "user='" + user + '\'' +
                ", authority='" + authority + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

Below are the repositories for the user and authority:
@Repository
public interface AuthorityRepository extends JpaRepository<Authority, AuthorityKey> {

    @Query("SELECT a.authority FROM Authority a WHERE a.user.id = :userId")
    Set<AuthorityType> findAuthorityTypesByUserId(@Param("userId") String userId);
}
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String>{
}

Here is the sut that is causing issues:
@Service
public class AuthorityService {

   public void assignAuthoritiesToUser(String userId, Set<AuthorityType> authorities) {
        User user = userRepository.findById(userId).orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException("User not found"));
        Set<AuthorityType> authoritiesToAssign = new HashSet<>(authorities);
        Set<AuthorityType> existingAuthorityTypes = authorityRepository.findAuthorityTypesByUserId(userId);
        if (!existingAuthorityTypes.isEmpty()) {
            authoritiesToAssign.removeAll(existingAuthorityTypes);
        }
        transactionTemplate.execute(status -> {
            authoritiesToAssign.stream().map(authorityValue -> {
                        Authority authority = new Authority();
                        authority.setAuthority(authorityValue);
                        authority.setUser(user);
                        return authority;
                    })
                    .forEach(authorityRepository::save);
            return null;
        });
    }

}

Below is the test class:
        @Test
        @DisplayName("Should assign authorities to user")
        void shouldAssignAuthoritiesToUser() {
            //setup
            String userId = "xst3147-68f0-42o8-a444-191478d4c86y7"; 
            Set<AuthorityType> authorities = Set.of(USER_READ, USER_CREATE);
            //execute
            authorityService.assignAuthoritiesToUser(userId, authorities);
            //verify
            authorities = authorityRepository.findAuthorityTypesByUserId(userId);
            assertThat(authorities).isNotEmpty();
            assertThat(authorities).hasSize(2);
        }

The error is like below:
: could not execute statement [Duplicate entry 'xst3147-68f0-42o8-a444-191478d4c86y7' for key 'user.PRIMARY'] [insert into user (first_name,last_name,username,id) values (?,?,?,?)]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.AbstractMutationExecutor.performNonBatchedMutation(AbstractMutationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.MutationExecutorSingleNonBatched.performNonBatchedOperations(MutationExecutorSingleNonBatched.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.AbstractMutationExecutor.execute(AbstractMutationExecutor.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.mutation.InsertCoordinator.doStaticInserts(InsertCoordinator.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.mutation.InsertCoordinator.coordinateInsert(InsertCoordinator.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2873)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:632)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:499)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1423)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:504)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2339)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:1996)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:439)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:561)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'xst3147-68f0-42o8-a444-191478d4c86y7' for key 'user.PRIMARY'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:118)

Hibernate Logs statements:
Hibernate: 
    select
        u1_0.id,
        u1_0.first_name,
        u1_0.last_name,
        u1_0.username 
    from
        user u1_0 
    where
        u1_0.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        a1_0.authority 
    from
        authority a1_0 
    where
        a1_0.user_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        a1_0.authority,
        a1_0.user_id 
    from
        authority a1_0 
    where
        (
            a1_0.authority, a1_0.user_id
        ) in ((?, ?))
Hibernate: 
    select
        null,
        u1_0.first_name,
        u1_0.last_name,
        u1_0.username 
    from
        user u1_0 
    where
        u1_0.id=?
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        authority
        (authority, user_id) 
    values
        (?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        user
        (first_name, last_name, username, id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?)

It seems when saving an authority entity, it tries to insert a record in the user table. Normally it shouldn't happen since the record is already in the user table.
I will appreciate any help in solving this issue.
Best Regards,
Rando.
P.S
The exception is thrown in save method below:
            authoritiesToAssign.stream().map(authorityValue -> {
                        Authority authority = new Authority();
                        authority.setAuthority(authorityValue);
                        authority.setUser(user);
                        return authority;
                    })
                    .forEach(authorityRepository::save); // this method throws the exceptions

the complete stack trace
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement [Duplicate entry 'xst3147-68f0-42o8-a444-191478d4c86y7' for key 'user.PRIMARY'] [insert into user (first_name,last_name,username,id) values (?,?,?,?)]; SQL [insert into user (first_name,last_name,username,id) values (?,?,?,?)]; constraint [user.PRIMARY]

    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:290)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:241)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:565)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:794)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:152)
    at com.accnt.app.identityaccesscontrol.authority.service.AuthorityService.assignAuthoritiesToUser(AuthorityService.java:101)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:351)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:765)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:173)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:765)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:64)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:173)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:765)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:173)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:765)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:173)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:765)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:173)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:765)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:173)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:765)
    at org.springframework.security.authorization.method.AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:765)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:765)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    at com.accnt.app.identityaccesscontrol.authority.service.AuthorityService$$SpringCGLIB$$0.assignAuthoritiesToUser(<generated>)
    at com.accnt.app.identityaccesscontrol.authority.service.AuthorityServiceIT$UserWithAuthorities.shouldAssignAuthoritiesToUser(AuthorityServiceIT.java:134)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement [Duplicate entry 'xst3147-68f0-42o8-a444-191478d4c86y7' for key 'user.PRIMARY'] [insert into user (first_name,last_name,username,id) values (?,?,?,?)]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.AbstractMutationExecutor.performNonBatchedMutation(AbstractMutationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.MutationExecutorSingleNonBatched.performNonBatchedOperations(MutationExecutorSingleNonBatched.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.AbstractMutationExecutor.execute(AbstractMutationExecutor.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.mutation.InsertCoordinator.doStaticInserts(InsertCoordinator.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.mutation.InsertCoordinator.coordinateInsert(InsertCoordinator.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2873)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:632)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:499)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1423)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:504)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2339)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:1996)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:439)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:561)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'xst3147-68f0-42o8-a444-191478d4c86y7' for key 'user.PRIMARY'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:118)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1061)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1009)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1320)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:994)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:194)



Where do you create User? Show us method that trows the exception.

Looks like assignAuthoritiesToUser missing @Transactional

CREATE TABLE 'user' - don't do that.

@K.Nicholas I shouldn't do it because it is a reserved word like group, right?

@talex I am using transaction template to limit only for the SQL statement that I want to atomic

userRepository.findById(userId) should be in the same hibernate session as authorityRepository::save. Otherwise user entity get detached. It seems that hibernate can't understand that that entity already in database and try to save it.

userRepository.findById(userId) should be in the same hibernate session as authorityRepository::save. Otherwise user entity get detached. It seems that hibernate can't understand that that entity already in database and try to save it.
